# Mysql regexp tag HTML

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

I have an HTML code saved in the database in the Message_html field

```
Dear CUSTOMER, <br />
<br />
Please be advised that the following document has been moved:<br />
Document number: D4D4D4D4D4D<br />
<br />
<table border="1">
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Movimento</th>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:35</td>
        <td>Juntada de contrarrazões</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">ALERT - REPRESENTATIONS</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:38</td>
        <td>Juntada de certidão</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">SUCCESS - CERTIFICATE</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:39</td>
        <td>Juntada de alvará</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">NOTICE - PERMIT</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
If you are no longer interested in receiving the push, access the link:: <a href="push.aspx">Exit</a><br />
<br />
<b>ATTENTION: this email is generated in an automated way, please do not reply.</b>
```

I need to check if it has the word CERTIFICATE in the table column

```
<td><a href="ver.aspx">CERTIFICATE</a></td>
```

Regular expression used in MYSQL

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('<td><a href="ver.aspx">SUCCESS - CERTIFICATE</a></td>', '>[^<td><a*]*CERTIFICATE*[</a></td>]') AS verify;

    REGEXP_INSTR(k.Message_html, '>[^<td><a*]*CERTIFICATE*[</a></td>]')
```

> Cannot find record

```
SELECT
*
FROM table as k

Where

WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(k.Message_html, concat('>[^<td><a*]*','CERTIFICATE,'*[</a></td>]')) > 0;
```

And regexp doesn't find the word inside the table

Since there is the word CERTIFICATE

Contents of the words table

```
word_id word
1 SUBJECT
2 DECISION
3 ORDER
4 SENTENCE
5 PETITION
6 CERTIFICATE
7 AMENDMENT TO THE INITIAL PETITION
8 NOTIFICATION - NOTIFICATION
9 EXTRACT
10 PETITION - PETITION
11 NOTIFICATION
12 MANIFESTATION
13 OTHER PARTS
14 REPRESENTATIONS
```

Comment: What does `Cannot find record` mean? That's not a MySQL error message.

Comment: If the query isn't returning any rows, that depends on the `WHERE` clause, not the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: `[^<td><a*]` doesn't do what you think. It matches a single character that isn't `<`, `t`, `d`, `>`, `a`, or `*`.

Comment: I put the query where is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `REGEXP_INSTR()` if you're just testing whether a string matches a regexp. Use `RLIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS k
WHERE k.Message_html RLIKE '<td><a [^<]*CERTIFICATE'
```

`[^<]*` will match anything that isn't the start of another tag, so it will match if the `<a>` contains `CERTIFICATE` in its text.

To join with the words table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS k 
JOIN words p ON k.Message_html RLIKE CONCAT('<td><a [^<]*', p.word);
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a541f2/2)

Comment: SELECT 
*
FROM
  table AS k
  JOIN words p
    ON k.Message_html RLIKE CONCAT('<td><a [^<]*', p.word);
 
When I put the concat to get the words in another table it didn't work!

Comment: The query executes, but when I put the concat it doesn't find any result. Since removing the concat function and adding the word CERTIFICATE locates.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! I apologize because I put the clause and k.id

Answer (score 0):

This would find your certificate

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('<td><a href="ver.aspx">SUCCESS - CERTIFICATE</a></td>'
, '(<td><a href="ver.aspx">).*CERTIFICATE.*(</a></td>)') AS verify;

    SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('Dear CUSTOMER, <br />
<br />
Please be advised that the following document has been moved:<br />
Document number: D4D4D4D4D4D<br />
<br />
<table border="1">
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Movimento</th>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:35</td>
        <td>Juntada de contrarrazões</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">ALERT - REPRESENTATIONS</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:38</td>
        <td>Juntada de certidão</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">SUCCESS - CERTIFICATE</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22/07/2021 15:39</td>
        <td>Juntada de alvará</td>
        <td><a href="ver.aspx">NOTICE - PERMIT</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
If you are no longer interested in receiving the push, access the link:: <a href="push.aspx">Exit</a><br />
<br />
<b>ATTENTION: this email is generated in an automated way, please do not reply.</b>', '(<td><a href="ver.aspx">).*CERTIFICATE.*(</a></td>)') AS verify;
```

Comment: SELECT
*
FROM
  table AS k
  JOIN words p
    ON REGEXP_INSTR(k.Message_html, CONCAT('(<td><a href=").*', p.word, '.*(</a></td>)'))

When I put the concat to get the words in another table it didn't work!

Comment: instr gives you back the char index of the foundf pattern in case of the second query a 347, so what do you try to join? make a full [mre] and ask a new question then this is answered

Comment: Sorry! The query executes, but when I put the concat it doesn't find any result. Since removing the concat function and adding the word CERTIFICATE locates.

Comment: let me guess you have a table with lots of html and you want to find out if any of the word lists fit? a full mre4, would include bith ta bles and a rewsultset you search

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! I apologize because I put the clause and k.id